# how to change storage engine of database in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL database. The default storage engine is `MyISAM`.

I want to change it to `InnoDB`.

I can change it table by table , but i want to change it one time that affect all the tables .

How can I change the database storage engine? I tried it but seems there is no option in `phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When logged in go to the table you want to change then click the operations tab. From there you can change the storage type, as well as a few other options

[Online Doc](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-change-table-storage-engine/)

Comment: actually i want to change the database storage engine one time that can affect all the tables . not table by table .

Comment: You can set it at the time of database creation

Comment: where i can set the storage engine when creating the database , i couldn't find it .

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286813/how-to-set-default-storage-engine-innodb-in-xampp-for-linux1-7-3a It's not using phpmyadmin though

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way to change the default engine is to **log on phpMyAdmin** and then go to **Variables >> storage engine**

**click edit** and type **InnoDB**.

the default storage engine is now InnoDB

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_storage_engine

Comment: Flag -MySQL storage engine- link purposes ~ignore message~

Comment: FYI; This works with WAMP.. for XAMPP find it in Operations tab. Thanks @Gurey

Answer (score 8):

Steps:

1. Click on the table for which you have to change the storage engine.
2. Click on operations.
3. Option to change the storage engine is inside the field set

Answer (score 2):

the best answer i got was

> The easiest way is just to go to the mysql config file (my.ini in
>   windows, my.cnf in Linux) and just add this: [mysqld]
>   default-storage-engine=InnoDB   .

i think that will do the trick easily .

thanks for the help........... :D

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in phpMyAdmin to change the storage type at a time. You have to change each table in operations tab.

Comment: Then you can export the tables and create one new DB with new storage type and import it.

Comment: Some versions of phpMyAdmin have this option. I just found out. My version 3.5.8.2 didn't have this option.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the table name, then click on operations, there you can change the server engine one table at a time.

A+ Computer Solutions- Belize

Comment: Signatures are bad form.